# Select using long variable vs MD5 performance wise

Tags: php, mysql, select, md5

Let's say I have a big table (100000+ entries) with long variables (URLs, like 100-250 characters). Would it make sense for better performance to have a MD5 hash as a seperate field next to it for fetching single rows from the table?

```
SELECT * FROM `urls` WHERE `url` = 'http://long-phrase...' LIMIT 1;
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `urls` WHERE `url_md5` = MD5('http://long-phrase...') LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: If you have an index of that md5 column I would say *Yes*. Try using `explain` to see

Comment: What do you mean better performance? Won't  using `MD5` slow down you run time?

Comment: I would guess that by using an INDEX is enough: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html Read also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html

Comment: 250 chars can still be indexed, and should perform about as well as using the md5 version.

Comment: @PHPNooB - MD5 is fast. (That's one reason why it's unsuitable for password hashing).

Comment: @Spudley Thanks for clearing that up. Never thought of it like that. But, still it can not make anything faster than a raw query

Comment: or can it ? I have no idea

Comment: @PHPNooB - only one MD5 call will be made during the query, so yes, it will be slower because of the hashing operation, but the difference that causes will be utterly marginal. The question is whether the improved performance resulting from matching the shorter string would be greater than the performance lost from the MD5 hash. I suspect that it would, but both sides of the equation are tiny so it probably doesn't make a huge amount of difference. As others have said, a suitable index is the single most important thing for speeding up a query; everything else is tinkering round the edges.

Comment: A pro for MD5 is that the hash is of fixed length, which can help when you want to create indexes. A con for MD5 is that it is not guaranteed to be unique. Two different inputs can result in the same hash (as is the case for all hash algorithms).

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that using an INDEX is enough, and here is why, written in a prosaic mood on a snowish sunday:

A database stores its rows in files, one after another:

```
 id url          name       descr         visited
  1 http://...   somewhere  i like it     2013-01-01
  2 http://...   wherever   i dislike it  2013-01-02
  ...
```

You will have this data on the disk roughly like this:

```
 [s:35:http://...s:9:somewhere...][s:45:http://...s:9:wherever...][...]
```

A bunch of bytes, lots of them. If you ask the DB to search for a given term the db has to scan the "rows" by scanning through the file and apply the search term. Let's say you have 1 million rows, the DB has to scan 1 million rows. Let's say you want to search for the "url"-field in the rows. And let's say you make it easier to "search" since you shortened (or extended, do a md5 of "http://goo.gl/P0Gwz") the string: You still have to search 1 million rows.

On the other hand, if you just could search an ORDERED list of rows, that would [really speed things up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). So, let's say the DB now stores the rows not ordered by the time you INSERTed the rows but ordered by the "url"-field. Now the DB has to reorder all the stored bytes on the disk as soon as you INSERT a new row. Of coz, you are now able to search much faster, but the INSERT operation is much slower. And do not forget: Tomorrow you want to search for the "descr"-field. What now? Reorder the whole file? Keep 2 copies of the file?

A better approach is to use a register, an ordered list with a reference to where to find a "row". That idea is as old as real world libraries are: Just place the books into shelfs one after another, number it, and create lists: One ordered by author name, one ordered by year of publishing, one by title etc. Any given person who wants to search for an author picks the author-register, scans over the names via a binary-search-like-approach (if the person is clever), gets the number of the book, goes to the shelves and quickly picks up the book.

That "register" thingy is also called an "INDEX": An ordered list of references to position of the referenced row on the disk:

```
 [s:35:http://...s:9:somewhere...][s:45:http://...s:9:wherever...][...]
       ^                               ^                           ^
       |                               |                           |
       |                               |                           |
 i1   -------------------------------- ^                           |
 i2   ------------------------------------------------------------------>
 i3   -^                                                           |
 i100 -------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Eg, you could now check `i50` to see if your search term matches. If the index-function points to something bigger than 50 you check i75 in the next round, if it is less than 50 you check i25 and so on.

To give you numbers: Given 1 million rows, and you search for the "url"-field you have to scan:

- 1 million rows in the worst case to find your url ("it's not in here").
- 0.5 million rows on average ("equal distribution").
- log2(10^6) == 20 checks against the url in the INDEX in the worst case.
- log2(10^6)-1 == 19 checks against the url in the INDEX on average.

And tomorrow you will have 2 million rows. Now you have to scan over 2 million rows by not using an INDEX and you would have to scan ~ 20 times max to find either the correct record or nothing. Millions of string comparisons vs 20. You see how much more impact the use of an INDEX has.

Read more about the topic here:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html